how it looks like when pcb damage with over power issue and components damage due to aging of pcb?
This PCB looks aged and damaged components but I doubt whether an over power issue has caused the PCB to be damaged. please can someone expert in this field explain this to me. I used the monitor through a UPS.

Looks to me like corrosion on that darkened trace, underneath the solder mask. Likely culprit is a leaky elco. I'd check C805.

The traces look fine, if you have a question on if they are working or not get a meter and check the continuity (should be low, below 1Ohm from point to point.)
If traces get hot, it usually also carbonizes the FR4 around the trace, not just the silkscreen on the trace itself. The traces are not delaminated which also usually happens during heating.
It almost looks like some kind of liquid was on the PCB at some time (as there is what looks to be brown in areas all over), which usually creates failures.

Thank you, Voltage Spike. It is not working right now. I claimed the warranty but was rejected saying there were burn marks on PCB.

There's nothing obvious visually from what I can see.
The PCB has some stressed high-voltage components on it, and for it to fail due to some kind of power line transient (eg. lightning storm) would not be unusual.

Hi Sphero, One image has failed to be uploaded.  I used the monitor through an ups. Thank you for the answer anyway please see the other picture if u can. thank you again

I reviewed both images before answering.

The GND trace between D815, C805 is a little suspicious, how the board is dark around the pins. Doesn't seem to have any further effects, though, just visual discoloration.

thanks a lot Sphero

Sphero, is it possible to save the diodes, SMDs, and other small components in such good condition I mean visually there are no damages on them, if there were a high voltage or lightning storm.

Sometimes there is visual damage, but it's also possible they could fail with a fuse or similar device preventing them from exploding etc. The SO-8 part with 7 pins (and a slot between pins 8 and 6) in the lower image (center L-R and about 1/3 of the way up) would be a prime suspect IMO.
